# How to run all web tests by command line

Tags: c#, .net, testing, command-line, webtest

I have dedicated DLL project for webtests. I know how to run specified webtest

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE>mstest /testcont
ainer:"MyPath\PostAccessToken.webtest" /resultsfile:MyResultPath\MyResults.trx
```

But how can I run all webtests from this library by one command? If I give DLL path as testcontainer then I get message "no tests found"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

MSTest /testcontainer:PostAccessToken.dll

Comment: I get message "No tests to execute..."

Comment: I think you have to check the path of test case dll.

Comment: If path will wrong, MsTest will return missing file etc.

Comment: Sections 4 and 5 of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182490.aspx say that the command will execute all the tests in the DLL. The "No tests to execute" message suggests that you are referring to the wrong DLL.