# How to run webtests by command line

Tags: c#, command-line, jenkins, continuous-integration, webtest

I have some webtest, which I want to connect with Jenkins. But I can not find solution how to run assembly with webtests by command line. How can I do it?

I try something like this

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE"

mstest /testcontainer:"C:\Jenkins\_code\webTestLibrary.dll"
```

I get information "No tests find". What do I wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run all web tests by command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575634/how-to-run-all-web-tests-by-command-line)

Comment: Please do not write multiple versions of the same question.